# Subtitle not shown in Videos

Tags: nvidia, videos, subtitles

Is it a bug or is it a video card driver problem?

If the latter what is my best option having an Asus notebook with Geforece 540m and an intel HD 3000. (Yes I have optimus).

Nvidia prime doesn't seems to work with 340 driver. nvidia-xsettings (not sure if this is the exact command) doesn't work it says "nvidia is not a recognizable command"
Nvidia Gui settings doesn't show anything.

No I won't use VLC.

Thank you for anyone helping me!

Comment: SMPlayer has subtitles without problem

Answer (score 1):

That has nothing to do with your graphics card. Are you sure the file you are trying to play has subtitles? Or are you trying to open  a subtitle file?

Also, if you have your graphics drivers correctly installed you should have a `NVIDIA X Server Settings` icon in your Applications menu. The correct console command is `nvidia-settings`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually used the correct command but it still says the same. The video itself doesn't have subtitle but I have one as an external subtitle. it's srt so it shouldn't be a problem. Other players have no problem with it. I tried drag and drop and the cogwheel icon  to load it manually

The icon you are talking about is there, but it has only 2 options in the list. I can't change what my computer use, nvidia or intel hd.
I remember in Luna I had to open the x server settings from bumblebee  and everything showed up correctly.

Comment: With `nvidia-prime` you can only use one graphics card at a time. That means you won't see the full menu unless you switch to the nvidia card first.

Also, have you tried the same srt file with other players?

Comment: So basically that means I used the Intel HD graphics then? If yes than I'll have no problem setting up my system.

That still doesn't solve the srt issue tho. Yes of course I tried VLC under windows

Comment: finally I got the video card working with indicator and stuff but yeah the subtitle was not graphics driver problem. it's still not working